# minimum value of $y= \frac {x^n+a}{x^m}$

Tags: inequality

**Question**

if $n>m$, $\frac {a}{x^m} > 0$ and $x^{n-m} > 0$,prove $y= \frac {x^n+a}{x^m}$ is minimum when
$x= \sqrt[n]{\frac {am}{n-m}}$ and value of minimum is equal to $y= \frac{n}{m}\sqrt[n]{(\frac {am}{n-m})^{n-m}}$

**My idea**

i know that if $P=x^n\times y^m\times...\times t^l$ is constant,then $S=x+y+...+t$ is minimum when $$\frac{x}{n}=\frac{y}{m}=...=\frac{t}{l}$$

and $y= \frac {x^n+a}{x^m}=x^{n-m}+ \frac {a} {x^m}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\left(x^{n-m}\right)^{\frac1{n-m}}\cdot\left(\frac a{x^m}\right)^{\frac1m}=a^{\frac1m}$$
is certainly constant.

Comment: finally i solved it with your hint. so i accept it.

Comment: Well done! Note that the idea was simply to get rid of any $x$, in order to get a constant. Making the exponents $0$ is the easiest way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would involve derivatives. To find an extrema of a function we need to take its derivative and find its zeros:
$$y'={nx^{n-1}x^m-mx^{m-1}(x^n+a)\over x^{2m}}\\
nx^{n-1}x^m-mx^{m-1}(x^n+a)=0\\
x^{m-1}(nx^n-mx^n-am)=0\\
x^n={ma\over n-m}\\
x_0=\sqrt[n]{{ma\over n-m}}\\
$$

We are still not done and need to prove that $x_0$ is a minimum. I leave it for you, but if you'd like me to show the solution, I will do it.

Comment: thanks for your solution.but even the book itself mentioned that there are ways to find minimum and maximum values with derivative but book don't want to use them because it's on inequality chapter.

Comment: Ok, next time it would be better if you mention such details in your question :)

Comment: well i just tagged inequality.if i wanted derivatives, i would have included calculus tag.

Comment: Note that it can only be a minimum because 1) The function is $C^\infty$ on $]0,\infty[$. 2) $y'=0$ only once. 3) if $x\to0$ or $x\to\infty$ we have $y\to\infty$. @user2838619 we're happy to hear that you tag your questions carefully, but unfortunately not every user would do that, which makes we can't let our answers be influenced by the tagging. It is recommended to mention which methods you prefer.

Comment: @barto nice, thank you!